# CentOS 7 disk space

Tags: linux, centos, hard-drive, df

I have a Centos7 server in which when executing the command `df -h` the occupied disk space is of 90GB but if I do a `du -sh / *` the sum of all directories does not correspond to 90GB, in this case it is around 60GB.

What could be causing this difference in occupied disk space values?

Comment: Is the filesystem ext4? If so, 5% of all space is reserved for root by default.

Comment: the filesystem is simfs

Answer (score 0):

there are some exception that may result on what you are experiencing like:

1- If you delete a file in some file managers or GUI environments, it may be put into a trash area where it can be undeleted. 
As long as the file can be undeleted, its space is still consumed. and it will be calculated on the du -h command.

2- If the file is open by a process, the data remains. Only when the processes have closed the file is the file deleted. 
The output fuser -m or lsof on a mount point includes the processes that have a file open on that filesystem, even if the file is deleted.

Comment: i've already test with 2 option and gave me this results: [http://i63.tinypic.com/de5pwp.png]

The total space with the `du-sh` continues to be 60GB occupied